# AttributeError: '<Class name>' object has no attribute 'request'

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web-applications

I defined a method for rendering pages:

```
def doRender(handler, tname='index.html',values = {}):
    temp = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
                        'templates/'+tname)
    if not os.path.isfile(temp):
        return False

    newval = dict(values)
    newval['path'] = handler.request.path

    user = users.get_current_user()
    url = users.create_login_url(handler.request.uri)
    url_linktext = 'Login'

    if user:
        url = users.create_logout_url(handler.request.uri)
        url_linktext = 'Logout'

    newval['user'] = user
    newval['url'] = url
    newval['url_linktext'] = url_linktext

    outstr = template.render(temp, newval)
    handler.response.out.write(outstr)
    return True
```

Also, I have these classes:

**GruposHandler**

```
class GruposHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):    
    def get(self):
        self.obtenerPagina()

    def obtenerPagina(self, pOpcion = None, pMensajeInformacion = None):
        opcion = pOpcion if pOpcion is not None else self.request.get('opcion') 
        usuario = obtenerUsuario()
        rsGrupos = obtenerGruposAll()
        listaGruposCreadosPorUsuario = []
        #
        #

        for grupo in rsGrupos: 
            if grupo.creadoPorUsuario == usuario:
                listaGruposCreadosPorUsuario.append(grupo)

        blahh...

        if opcion == 'gruposMios':
            doRender(self, 'grupos_mios.html', {'listaGruposCreadosPorUsuario':listaGruposCreadosPorUsuario,
                                                'informacion':pMensajeInformacion})
```

**NuevoGrupoHandler**

```
class NuevoGrupoHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        nombre = self.request.get('nombre')
        descripcion = self.request.get('descripcion')

        #comprobar que no exista un grupo con el mismo nombre
        obj = Grupo.get_by_key_name(nombre)
        if obj:
            doRender(self, 'nuevo_grupo.html', {'mensaje_descripcion':'Ya existe un grupo con ese nombre.'})
        else:
            grupo = model.Grupo(key_name = nombre, nombre=nombre, descripcion = descripcion);
            grupo.put()
            grupoHandler = GruposHandler()
            grupoHandler.obtenerPagina("gruposMios", 'Informacion: un nuevo grupo fue agregado.')
```

When webapp receive an HTTP GET request to the URL /nuevogrupo, it instantiates the NuevoGrupoHandler class and calls the instance's get method.
So at this point, everything works as expected

```
def main():
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
                                          ('/nuevogrupo', NuevoGrupoHandler),
                                          etc...
```

but when I call method GruposHandler.obtenerPagina() from NuevoGrupoHandler.post(), when the method doRender() inside obtenerPagina()
is reached, an exception is thrown at this line:

```
newval['path'] = handler.request.path
```

This is the stacktrace I'm getting:

> AttributeError: 'GruposHandler' object has no attribute 'request'

So it seems that something is not properly setted when it is not called from the webapp.WSGIApplication instance. I'm not so sure.

Sorry I could not explain the problem better.

What should I do to avoid that exception.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is doRender() an instance method of your GruposHandler?

Comment: Hi Alex. doRender() doesn't belong to any class. It's just inside the file that contains the other classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about google-app-engine, but the issue is from your side, not from the WSGIApplication.

In `NuevoGrupoHandler.post` method, you're instanciate a new `GruposHandler()`, that you use for rendering. And this instance doesn't have `request` attribute, that cause your exception.

My approach would be to copy the request attribute from your current instance to the new one:

```
grupoHandler = GruposHandler()
grupoHandler.request = self.request # <<< add this
grupoHandler.response = self.response # <<< and this
grupoHandler.obtenerPagina("gruposMios", 'Informacion: un nuevo grupo fue agregado.')
```

Then your new instance handler will have the same request as the current one, and the exception will be avoided.

**Edit:**

By the way, if you want to just use an external method like this, it would be better to create another baseclass that implement the `doRender`, and inherit from it for `GruposHandler` and `NuevoGrupoHandler`:

```
class RenderRequestHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def obtenerPagina(self, ...):
        pass

    def do_render(self):
        pass

class GruposHandler(RenderRequestHandler):
    pass

class NuevoGrupoHandler(RenderRequestHandler):
    pass
```

And implement both method in the baseclass. :)

Comment: Many thanks Tito.
I also found another way to solve this particular problem.
I just replaced these lines:
grupoHandler = GruposHandler()
grupoHandler.obtenerPagina("gruposMios", 'Informacion: un nuevo grupo fue agregado.')

by this:

self.redirect('/grupos?opcion=gruposMios')

But I'll use your approach! =)